# Dynamically apply a function fed by Input[]

Tags: dynamic

Here is a bit of code:

```
funlist = {Plot,ListPlot};
Input[Panel[PopupMenu[Dynamic@whichfun, funlist], "blabla"],Dynamic@whichfun]
```

The idea here is to select what function you want to use (`Plot` or `ListPlot` in that case) and to give the expression you want to be evaluated by this function (for example `x,{x,0,1}` for `Plot`).

I have been struggling with this code for a few hours so if anyone has an idea.

I am aware that something like:

```
PopupMenu[Dynamic@whichfun, funlist]
InputField[Dynamic[expr], String, ContinuousAction -> True]
Dynamic@(whichfun @@ (ToExpression@expr))
```

with `InputField` fed by `{x, {x, 0, 1}}` would work.

Comment: `Input` is a must?

Comment: `Input` is a wish*. If it's not possible then I'll give up.

Comment: You could strip away the `Dynamic` stuff that gets in the way: `Input[....]/. Dynamic[f_, ___] :> f`

Comment: @ssch, it indeed works! Answer it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels like a bit of a hack but at least works.
The output looks something like:

```
(Plot)[x,{x,0,1}]//InputForm
(* Dynamic[whichfun, ImageSizeCache -> {33., {0., 8.}}][x, {x, 0, 1}] *)
```

After stripping away that `Dynamic` it works as expected:

```
funlist = {Plot, ListPlot};
Input[
  Panel[PopupMenu[Dynamic@whichfun, funlist], "blabla"],
  Dynamic@whichfun] /. Dynamic[f_, ___] :> f
(* Gives a plot *)
```